# Is Post-pixel-shader-blending always guaranteed in DirectX 10 and 11?

Tags: directx, directx-11

Under DirectX 9, it was still necessary to query the device for the capability bit "post pixel shader blending" on a per-texture-basis.

This functionality now doesn't exist any more, but DirectX 11 has the whole new Output-Merger_State OM, which basically does what PPSB says on the tin.

I can't find anywhere that it says that DX10 and DX11 guarantee that they offer this capability, so can I always rely on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK yes, it's always available.

Comment: I think "AFAIK" is as close as anyone is going to get to DirectX :)